# Not transitioning to next in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want the the pygame interface to switch to a new page (from a page order that is determined by random) when the right prompted buttons are pressed. While it initializes, the page isn't transitioning to the next page stated in the for loop. Alternatively, putting everything in the while true loop just loops between the contents of func1 and func2 endlessly with no regards to keypresses. Any insight would be appreciated.

Running on Python 3x and pygame 1.9.5

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random

control1 = 0
control2= 0

pygame.init()

display_width = 500
display_height = 500

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

gd = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)

pygame.event.pump()

def func1():
    global control1
    control1 = 1
    gd.fill(white)
    letter = myfont.render("Press w",0,(black))
    gd.blit(letter,(100,100))
    pygame.display.flip()

def func2():
    global control2
    control2 = 1
    gd.fill(white)
    letter = myfont.render("Press d",0,(black))
    gd.blit(letter,(100,100))
    pygame.display.flip()

my_sample = random.sample(range(2), 2)

for i in my_sample:
    if my_sample[i] == 0:
        func1()
        if control1 == 0:
            continue
    if my_sample[i] == 1:
        func2()
        if control2 == 0:
            continue
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w and control1 == 1:
            control1 = 0

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d and control2 == 1:
            control2 = 0

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what the goal is, but I can address the issues you are having. The pages aren't transitioning because, even though you are registering key presses, you are not updating which page is to be displayed within the while loop. You are correct that putting everything in the while loop just endlessly loops between func1() and func2() because you also need flags to indicate which to display. You look to have all the pieces, just not necessarily in the right place.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

display_width = 500
display_height = 500

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

gd = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)

pygame.event.pump()

def func1():
    global control1
    control1 = 1
    gd.fill(white)
    letter = myfont.render("Press d",0,(black))
    gd.blit(letter,(100,100))
    pygame.display.flip()

def func2():
    global control2
    control2 = 1
    gd.fill(white)
    letter = myfont.render("Press s",0,(black))
    gd.blit(letter,(100,100))
    pygame.display.flip()

def func3():
    global control2
    control2 = 1
    gd.fill(white)
    letter = myfont.render("Press w",0,(black))
    gd.blit(letter,(100,100))
    pygame.display.flip()

page1 = True
page2 = False
page3 = False

while True:    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                page1 = True
                page2 = False
                page3 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                page1 = False
                page2 = True
                page3 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                page1 = False
                page2 = False
                page3 = True    
    if page1:
        func1()
    elif page2:
        func2()
    elif page3:
        func3()

    pygame.display.update()
```

I took out all the random stuff and modified the code to show you a simple page switching program where the user presses the button and it switches the page displayed. From there you can add back in the random stuff. The key to note is the pages are flagged to know which one to display.